# Is it possible to do something automatically before opening .nb?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, system

Is it possible to do something before opening `.nb` ?

I mean,
When the Mathematica kernel(?) receives a command to open the `.nb`,
then the kernel is told **not to open it, but to do something else** as specified.
(As previously specified by the user)

There are many ways to open .nb, 1) double clicking, 2) open from menubar, 3)through hyperlink. 4)through code execution

But I guess there is basically a **time** in which the kernel receives the same **open command**. Catches that time and tells the kernel to do something else.

It may or may not be helpful, using code in the existing .nb is permitted.

There is a possibility that it is fundamentally impossible, but I am asking the question just in case.

Comment: The kernel is not really involved in the opening process. In fact, the kernel does not even need to be running. So I’m pretty sure that what you want is impossible

Comment: As @LukasLang intimates, it is the *front end* that opens notebooks, not the Kernel.  The front end is essentially just a pretty interface---it has very little user-facing computational capability itself.